# Slow image loading Nativescript

Tags: ios, iphone, image, listview, nativescript

i'm developing a mobile app with Nativescript.
In my app i have a list-view with some image objects which are downloaded from my google cloud storage bucket. I mean the src property of the image is something like: "https://storage.[...]/image-1.jpg".
Now on android everything is working fine, but when i tested it on the ios simulator and on the iphone device, it took a lot of time to load the picture.
It took something like 2 minutes to load a bunch of pics.
Anyone facing the same issue, how can i solve it?
Thank you!

UPDATE:
After two weeks with the mac broken now i can test again the app, but the problem is still there.
The issue is that just the images are not appearing but all the other components are working correctly with good performance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you, for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check debug->slow animations. Had same problem accidentally toggled slow animations.

Comment: Hi sorry if i reply now, but my mac was broken and i couldn't test the app. Unfortunately that wasn't the problem, slow animations is not enabled. The issue regards only the images that doesn't load, but all other components works good

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but i figured out what was the problem.
Basically it had to do with the layout.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what solved your problem? Other users might have similar problems and benefit from your solution.

Comment: Actually it was long time ago, i just saw by chance my answer and i said at least try to help by saying that it was a layout issue, this is what i remember. The image where in a layout that wasn't correctly diplayed